# I want to rank my magento website top on the first page of Google!

Tags: magento-1.9, search, seo, websites

I am building the new Magento website named "`Bookslab.in`" & now this website is on the `7th position` on the first page of the `Google`. I want to rank this website top on the first page of Google, so how to do this is there any website or any method to do this within one or two days. Website name is bookslab.in

Comment: any answer stacky's

Comment: I want Jesus to visit me this weekend.

Comment: Yeah if my website ranks top on Google definitely Jesus will visit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can give you guarantee not even GOOGLE that your website will be first in Google as Google's crawler is highly intelligent and their searching algorithms are damn smart but here few tricks which will help you to improve ranking.

1. First of all create 5-6 blogs on popular blogging sites for your websites(Same name/Title/slogans) even if its okay if it's contain one paragraph and give all links to your website.
   here is list of popular bloggin site:
   wordpress, blogger, tumbler, svbtle, google and lastly quora.
   **LOGIC:** Google crawl is very smart, more links pointing to your website your page will get up.
2. Use google's webmaster tool and register your website overthere.
   Webmasters - Google
3. Now do some social promoting activities make page in FB,
   open account in twitter and etc..
   **LOGIC:** In many cases social networking results comes first before the official website
4. Create one channel on youtube(Same name/Title/slogans) put some introductory videos. It hardly takes 30 mins to do it. Put description about your companies
   **LOGIC:** If google's crawler see that you met with all above points that means your site contains some truely-effective information and your page will get boost.
5. Keywords
   Understand required relevant keywords for your website and use it.
   Get keywords accuracy list from Google(Google keywords). see their frequency and match with your website content.
   Google Ad Words: Keyword Planner
6. Add geographical address to your website. you can register your physical location on Google.

**LOGIC:** It means that you are business address is verified by Google. That will help you for rating. have you ever seen if you type some famous hotels on Google you can see right hand side its ratting and all. this is nothing but register your physical address on it.
Verify a local business on Google

Few technical things that google except:
-Clean code (Make your website validate through HTML and CSS validator
-no grammer mistakes.
-Image compression
-If you are using jquery then use CDN version of google
-dont ever leave blank your title(It is the main thing that google crawler will observe)
-Dont use any copyrighted templates you will get caught easily.
-Clean content that will have some truely information-facts.

By following all points believe me your chances will get very high you can say 99% your website will be first results not immediately but it may take couple of days.